# Does $ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(\ln x+ x)=-\infty$ imply $ \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}f(\ln x+ x)=-\infty$. True or false? $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.

Attempt. I strongly believe that it is true. I can prove it easily when i have $\ln x$ instead of $\ln x+x$ using the epsilon-delta definition, but i am having a hard time with $x+\ln x$. I believe it has to do somehow with the fact that $x+\ln x$ is onto the reals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's true for _any_ value of $\lim f(x+\ln x)$, not just $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x+ \ln x) = -\infty$.

- Prove that the continuous function $g\colon x \mapsto x+\ln x$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ with $\lim_{0^+} g = -\infty$ and $\lim_{+\infty} g = +\infty$, so that it is a bijection from $(0\infty)$ to $(-\infty, \infty)$.
- Now, consider $g^{-1}\colon\mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$. We have $$g^{-1}(x) \xrightarrow[x\to -\infty]{} 0^+$$ so in particular by assumption on $f$ we get $f( g^{-1}(x) + \ln g^{-1}(x) ) \xrightarrow[x\to -\infty]{} -\infty$. But for $ x \in\mathbb{R}$, $g^{-1}(x) + \ln g^{-1}(x) = g( g^{-1}(x)) = x$ .

*Remark:* it works for any $a\in \mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, not only $-\infty$, as observed by Arthur in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=x e^{x}$. It is strictly positive for $x>0$, and  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}=0$. So $y = \log g(x)$ is defined for $x>0$, $y\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$, and 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(\log g(x)) = \lim_{y\to -\infty} f(y)\,.$$